# How to fix Matplotlib plotting Pandas Series blank data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting a csv read in by pandas using matplotlib and the following code.

Image of CSV data:

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.plot(dat['Forecast Hour'].iloc[0:45], dat['Forecasted End Time'].iloc[0:45],'b', marker='o')

plt.plot(dat['Forecast Hour'].iloc[0:46], dat['Forecasted Start Time'].iloc[0:46], 'r', marker='o')

bar = plt.bar(dat['Forecast Hour'].iloc[8:46], dat['Forecasted Event Length'].iloc[8:46], width=.8, color='gainsboro')

ax.tick_params(which='major',labelsize='12')
ax.grid(which='major', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle='-')
plt.xticks(rotation='90')
plt.xlabel('Forecast Run')
plt.ylabel('Forecasted Start/End Time')
plt.legend()
ax3 = ax.twinx()
mn, mx = ax.get_ylim()
ax3.set_ylim(0, 12)
ax3.set_ylabel('Forecasted Event Length')
```

When I try to run the following code I receive the error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11:00 PM'

When I convert the Nan values to blank spaces using:

```
dat = dat.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

The data will plot but also include the blank space data, like so (space between 9:00 pm and x axis):

Image of Graphed data
[image]

Ultimately, how do I a) stop matplotlib from plotting this "blank data" or b) make 9:00 pm the 0 point for my graph axes?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: did you try df.dropna() to just get rid of all the nan values?

Comment: When I add .dropna() I lose some of my data as the Forecasted Start Time and Forecasted End time are not perfectly matched up with respect to the Forecast Hour.

Comment: Matplotib doesn't know hoe to plot strings, you should convert all the strings that relate to date to a datetime object with `pd.to_datetime` that should solve some of your problems.

Comment: When I attempt to use pd.to_datetime I receive the following error: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-05 11:00:00     Do I need to add in exact dates along with the times in order for the pd.to_datetime function to work properly?